# there is no package called ‘rpart.plot’

Tags: r, macos, decision-tree, rpart, rattle

I am following Titanic Tutorial on DataCamp. After built the decision tree, the plotting for the decision tree just doesn't work, showing an error that

> there is no package called ‘rpart.plot’

Any idea how to fix this?

**libraries**

```
library(rattle)
library(rpart)
library(RColorBrewer)
```

**decision tree**

```
my_tree_two <- rpart(Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp + Parch + Fare + Embarked, 
                     data = train, 
                     method = 'class')
fancyRpartPlot(my_tree_two)
```

Comment: Have you tried to manually `install.packages('rpart.plot')`?

Comment: @loki He is using Datacamp's own interpreter, at times it is buggy and doesn't behaves as expected. If the package isn't available, I haven't been able to install on it so far.

Comment: @xmindata consider reporting it to Datacamp. These bugs should always be reported.

Comment: @loki yes I tried that, it's not working.

Comment: Like @Pj_ said, there are several packages I cannot install. Thank you guys.

Comment: @xmindata If the solution helped you, can you accept my answer so that it can help others too? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datacamp's Interpreter at times it is buggy and doesn't behaves as expected. If the package isn't available, you won't be able to install it.

Consider reporting it to Datacamp

Answer (score 4):

Please try installing "rpart.plot":

```
library("rpart.plot")
```

Comment: Thank you, problem fixed. It's because i didn't intall GTK+

Answer (score 4):

The rpart.plot package should first be installed, then loaded in order to be used.

```
install.packages("rpart.plot")
library(rpart.plot)
```

The package does not install when you install rplot and must be installed with the above commands.